# ActionScript 3: Error when try execute bitmap.draw();

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, bitmap

I'm creating a app in flash AS3, that make a snapshop from a movieClip (e.g. image) and send data to server (data is received with PHP). So, when app is executed on flash, the RAW data is sent to server and my file image is created. But, when i put flash Movie on HTML Source, and try execute on browser, the movie is loaded, but the action that is sending image to the server is not running.

Below is my code:

```
var jpgSource:BitmapData = new BitmapData( 600, 600 );
jpgSource.draw(image); // <--- PROBLEM!!!

// encode it to jpeg and convert it to byte array
    var jpgEncoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(85);
    var jpgStream:ByteArray = jpgEncoder.encode(jpgSource);

    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("./post-image?facebookID="+user.facebook.id);
        request.requestHeaders.push(new URLRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/octet-stream"));
        request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
        request.data = jpgStream;


    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
        loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, function(e:IOErrorEvent){
            trace(e.status);
            ExternalInterface.call("console.log","Request Response Status: " + e.text);
            //ExternalInterface.call("console.log",e);
        }, false, 0, true);

        loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(e:Event){
            trace( new String(loader.data));
            ExternalInterface.call("console.log",new String(loader.data));
        }, false, 0, true);

        loader.load(request);
```

Does anyone know what might be happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that flash (in the browser) is blocking the request due to security issues, especially if you are running that file locally. Try running it from the same server that is running the PHP and see if that helps. You could also go into the flash settings on your computer and add the swf folder as a trusted location. The flash IDE has different sandbox restrictions than flash in the browser. You also might try flashbug in firefox to see if you could display the error you are getting. Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for answer. I've tried to do this. I'm running app on local deploy server. I've also changed the configuration Local Playback Security to _Access Network_. But it did not work.

Comment: Try running this in firefox and add firebug + flashbug. If you get an error in your swf it will alert you in the browser instead of failing silently... helpful for tracking down unknown bugs.Also I assumer the local server is also running the PHP code? If not you might need to add a crossdomain.xml to the PHP server.

Comment: I've done it too. Gives no error. Just do not run `jpgSource.draw (image)`, I can not understand why.

What I want to do is hit a screenshot of the movie and send it to the server. Is there another way to do this?